# Find distinct child rows which have more than 1 parent in the same table Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with following structure

[image]

I need to identify all unique 1st level ids which have more than 1 0th level id
In this example , query should return 200, 400

How can I acheive that?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 1st_level_id
from your_table
group by 1st_level_id
having count(distinct 0th_level_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, I can as well do count(distinct 0th_level_id) = 1 if I want the 100,300 record set correct?

Comment: yes, that will give the records with only one 0th_level_id